# implementing crate-local traits for multiple generic types cause conflicting implementations

Tags: rust, template-specialization, specialization

Following code causes conflicting implementations error:

```rust
trait A<S> {}
trait B<S> {}
struct C<T>(T);

impl <T, S> B<S> for T
where T: A<S>
{}

impl<T, S> B<S> for C<T>
where T: B<S>
{}
```

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `B<_>` for type `C<_>`:
  --> src/lib.rs:11:1
   |
7  | / impl <T, S> B<S> for T
8  | | where T: A<S>
9  | | {}
   | |__- first implementation here
10 | 
11 | / impl<T, S> B<S> for C<T>
12 | | where T: B<S>
13 | | {}
   | |__^ conflicting implementation for `C<_>`
   |
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `A<_>` for type `C<_>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

`C` is a local type, can specialization resolve this problem?

Moreover, it works if we replace `A<S>` with `Fn(S)`, is a compiler hole?

```rust
trait B<S> {}

struct C<T>(T);

impl <T, S> B<S> for T
where T: Fn(S)
{}

impl<T, S> B<S> for C<T>
where T: B<S>
{}
```

Comment: I'm not totaly sure but this look similar to https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48869, more details here https://github.com/nox/rust-rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md

Comment: They are not the same, as `C<_>` is not a fundamental struct, so it's impossible to implement trait `A<_>` for type `C<_>` at downstream.